# SQL - How can I select the next value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 r2 I have a column 'Activity_ID' that's an integer and can have a range of values (i.e. 20, 21, 22, 28, 29, 37, 38, 41).

I have no way of knowing what Activity_ID will be next.

Is there any way to check for the next highest Activity_ID (and then do X once I have found it)?

M

Comment: A set of data and the desired result would came handy on your question. Right your question is unclear.

Comment: If you are setting the "next" value manually you are going to have issues with concurrency. Is this column an identity? Either way, you need to be cognizant of potential concurrency issues and write your code accordingly.

Comment: Why dont use an identity column instead? [IDENTITY PROPERTY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: It would help to see what you tried already, currently this question is too ambiguous  as it is not clear what is the input and what the desired results will be.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 or later, you would use `lag` or `lead`.  In 2008, you can simulate the same behavior with row number.  I am guessing here because your question didn't come with sample data, but it might look something like this:

```
;with CTE as 
  (select *
  , Row_Number() over (partition by Name order by ActivityCode) as RN 
  from MyTable)

select a.*, b.activitycode as NextHighestCode 
from CTE a
left join CTE b
on a.name = b.name
and a.RN = b.RN - 1
```

This will return the values in your table (replace `name` with whatever actual columns you have), and the next highest activity code for each row.  This may not handle ties in the way that you would expect, so you may want to add more columns to the `partition` clause if you are expecting them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  declare @tb table
  (
    orderNumber int identity(1,1),
    value int
  )

  insert into @tb values(20)
  insert into @tb values(21)
  insert into @tb values(22)
  insert into @tb values(28)
  insert into @tb values(29)
  insert into @tb values(37)
  insert into @tb values(38)
  insert into @tb values(41)



  declare @v table(
    activity_id int
  )

  insert into @v values(37)

    select 
        (select top 1 value from @tb t1 where  t1.value > v.activity_id)
     from @v v
```

Comment: why dont use just MAX() function?

Comment: What happens when two people are doing the same thing at the same time? They would both get the same value and everything is going to come apart.